# Is there a easy way to shut down python grpc server gracefully?

Tags: python, kubernetes, grpc

[Here](https://medium.com/@fedor/shutting-down-grpc-services-gracefully-961a95b08f8) is a blog explaining how to gracefully shutdown a GRPC server in kotlin.

Is this the only way to do it? Counting live calls and handling SIGTERM manually? This should have been normal behavior.

I couldn't find how to count live calls in python. Can someone point me to docs that will help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out there is a easy way instead of counting RPCs, here is how I got it done:

```
server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100))
{} = {}Impl()
add_{}Servicer_to_server({}, server)
server.add_insecure_port('[::]:' + port)
server.start()
logger.info('Started server at ' + port)
done = threading.Event()
def on_done(signum, frame):
    logger.info('Got signal {}, {}'.format(signum, frame))
    done.set()
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, on_done)
done.wait()
logger.info('Stopped RPC server, Waiting for RPCs to complete...')
server.stop(NUM_SECS_TO_WAIT).wait()
logger.info('Done stopping server')
```

Answer (score 1):

gRPC Python servers have a (newish) [method for this](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.Server.wait_for_termination). Just call `server.wait_for_termination()`

Comment: Does that handle SIGTERM?

Also see my answer

Comment: It doesn't handle SIGTERM